# Reuse Dynamically created view

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am dynamically creating say 300 views in For loop :

Ex:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 300; j++)
{
    Image image = new Image();
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/sample256.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

    Grid titleGrid = new Grid();
    titleGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    titleGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

    TextBlock titleText = new TextBlock();
    titleText.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    titleGrid.Children.Add(titleText);

    Grid subtitleGrid = new Grid();
    subtitleGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    subtitleGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

    TextBlock subtitleText = new TextBlock();
    subtitleText.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

    subtitleGrid.Children.Add(subtitleText);

    //add all views to root layout
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(image);
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(titleGrid);
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(subtitleGrid);
}
```

Now there is a lag in the app as I am adding new view each time, how can I reuse the already created views? I am working on Windows Phone 8 app.

Comment: Well, you can create a collection of Images/Views/Grids, will be something like: List<Image> usedImages. Then you can work with this list. But why do you need 300 views? Maybe there's simpler solution.

Comment: @Olter i am working on a screen when for each root layout will have 3 childern which is Image,and 2 text. Can you please show me eaxmple of what you are pointing to ?

Comment: Em, just saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190302/reusing-text-views-and-grid Don't ask duplicate questions, please.

Comment: @Olter yes  i had asked that earlier but did not get enough attention, can you please help me on that

Answer (score 1):

adding 300 items in the layout root will definatly make page load slow. you need to use controls that implement virtulization like listbox. here is how

ListBox XAML in your page.

```
<ListBox Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}">
                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Question}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Answer}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

your code behind

```
code to bind data 

  List<MyData> list = new List<MyData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            var data = new MyData();
            data.Question = "//yourquestion";
            data.Answer = "// your answer";
            data.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("yourimagepat"));
        }
        myListBox.ItemsSource = list;
```

Data Class

```
  public class MyData {
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public BitmapImage ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

**to take advantage of the virtulization please add your listbox in Grid control. otherwise it can throw out of memory exception and also will be slow**

Comment: Thanks in my case i dont have a list box its, custom class which extends panel

Comment: than try to extend it from virtualizedpanel

Comment: my collegue had even sent you the project via mail ? do you remember ?

Comment: Ah the same issue yes i remembered I did not find that much time to solve that problem I will try it tonight and if can fix the issue than will email back. :(

Comment: ok, i will be waiting for your reply

Comment: Please let me know or mail me if you are able to fix that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try using DataBinding feature instead of creating this .

```
 // You can bound items from your Class here

<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Margin="5"
 Width="450" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
 ItemsSource="{Binding SongsList}">
ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel CleanUpVirtualizedItemEvent="VirtualizingStackPanel_CleanUpVirtualizedItemEvent_1">
                </VirtualizingStackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>

 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
        <TextBlock Text="Artist:" Margin="2" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" Margin="2" />
        <TextBlock Text="CD:" Margin="10,2,0,2" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2" />
     </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

```
// your class should be like this
public Songs
{
 public string Artist{get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

// CodeBehind Just Add Data

```
ObservableCollection<Songs> SongsList=new ObservableCollection<SongsL();

for (int j = 0; j <= 300; j++)
{
   SongsList.Add(new Songs{Artist="Aritst Name",Name="Song Name"});
}

// Set this Collection from the codebehind or xaml .
ListBox1.ItemSource=SongsList; // it will the bind the public properties in this Songs.
```

[DataBinding Controls on Windows phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Data_Binding_to_controls_on_Windows_Phone)

[Msdn Databindin greference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207023(v=vs.105).aspx)

[Binding data Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488773/wpf8-c-binding-data-to-grid)

[Databinding from Jesse Liberty](http://jesseliberty.com/2010/11/10/windows-phone-from-scratch-6-data-binding-really/)

Comment: I tried this it gives me Out of memory error.any other solution

Comment: [StackReference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816569/why-do-i-get-an-outofmemoryexception-when-i-have-images-in-my-listbox?rq=1)